# With existing android apps that use ordinary signing, why can I update it even if I change the sign using Google Play App Signing?

Tags: android, google-play

I think using Google Play App Signing will change the app signature.
I think that Android apps can not be updated unless they have the same signature.
Why can I use Google Play App Signing to update my app?

Comment: The question is not very clear. Can you please elaborate what do you mean by the app signing will change the app signature?

Comment: @ReazMurshed I think that the signature will change when you migrate from an existing app signature to Google Play App Signing.

Comment: I also want to know if the signature does not change when migrating.

Comment: Now I am confused by what you meant by "migrating".

Comment: Sorry for not clear question. "migrating" means "Opt in to app signing by Google Play"
 for existing apps. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en#

Comment: @takahirom This [medium article on Google Play Signing](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/exploring-google-play-app-signing-b4d296f4ee9) may help with understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed the app signature is not changed. Sorry for the wrong question. So You can update the app even if you use Google Play Signing.

```
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile oldsign.apk   > local.sign
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile googleplaysign.apk  > googleplay.sign
diff local.sign googleplay.sign
// diffs are not shown
```